# Identity server 4 issuer uri and ssl certificate verification

Tags: asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I have ASP .NET Core 5 project which runs identity server 4. By default, the issuer URI is dynamic. When deployed on the server it runs on the server's internal IP address, the SSL certificate's SAN IP section is registered with this IP so SSL/TLS verification is acceptable. But on the client side, their IP address/domain will be changed after a certain period of time. They don't want to change the SSL certificate manually every time. Also, the domain or IP is not known so we can set the issuer URI when it is changed. Is there any way to solve this problem? How to avoid the SSL certificate changes every time the IP address gets changed? How to let the identity server URL gets SSL verified?